# If value will change, change few cells color

Tags: excel, vba, cells

i can't find answer for my issue, maybe you can helf me to solve this problem.
I want to change this VBA Script to have something like:

- if in column A value will change - run VBA Script
- for example, if in cell A2 or A3, or A4 and so on = 1, (cells B2, C2, E2, H2) will green and (D2, F2, G2 and J2) will rot.
  if A2 or A3 ...... = 2 (B2, C2,) will green, D2, F2 will rot

if A3 value will change, than change B3, C3
if A4 will change, change B4, C4 and so on

Values in column A user will change "by hand"

`Sub ChangeColor()`

`Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("csv_vorlage")`

`LastRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row`

`Set MyPlage = Range("A1:A" & LastRow)
'MsgBox (MyPlage)
For Each cell In MyPlage
    Select Case cell.Value
    Case Is = "1"
    Range("B2:F2").EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 3 'red
    Case Is = "2"
    cell.EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 4 'green
    Case Is = "3"
    cell.EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 4
    Case Is = "4"
    cell.EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 4
    Case Is = "5"
    cell.EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 4
    Case Is = "6"
    cell.EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 4
    Case Is = "7"
    cell.EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 4
    Case Is = "8"
    cell.EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 4
    Case Is = "9"
    cell.EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 4
    Case Is = "10"
    cell.EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 4
    Case Is = "11"
    cell.EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 4
    Case Is = "12"
    cell.EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 4
    Case Is = "13"
    cell.EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 4
    Case Is = "14"
    cell.EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 4
    Case Is = "15"
    cell.EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 4
    Case Is = "16"
    cell.EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 4
    Case Is = "17"
    cell.EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 4
    Case Is = "19"
    cell.EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 4
    Case Else
    cell.EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 0
End Select
Next
End Sub`

and how to do that ?

Comment: toi clarify, so even if just one cell in Column A (A2, A3 , or A100) changes it's values you want to color B2, C2, E2, H2 to green ?  what do you want to do the next time one of the cells in column A changes it's value ? keep it green? or now change to another color ?

Comment: my mistake sorry, if A3 value will change, than change B3, C3
if A4 will change, change B4, C4 and so on

Comment: How will cells in column A change? I mean, are they the result of some formula in them or is the user going to change them "by hand"?

Comment: Values in column A user will change "by hand"

Comment: furthermore your coloring rules are not so clear to me: you may also want to add some examples of a "before" and "after" scenarios

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First move your code to `Worksheet_Change` event, and only check the values if a value in column A was modified.

Use `Select Case` to add multiple scenarios you want to check against when modifying the color of to Green.

**Code**

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim LastRow As Long

LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1:A" & LastRow)) Is Nothing Then
    Select Case Target.Value
        Case "1", "2", "3", "4" '<-- put the rest of your cases here
            Range("B" & Target.Row & ":C" & Target.Row & ",E" & Target.Row & ":H" & Target.Row).Interior.ColorIndex = 4  'green
        Case Else
            Range("B" & Target.Row & ":C" & Target.Row & ",E" & Target.Row & ":H" & Target.Row).Interior.ColorIndex = 0
    End Select
End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

your narrative isn't clear as long as actual coloring rules are concerned

but since you clarifed cell will be changed "manually" by the user, then you can go like follows:

- in the "csv_vorlage" worksheet code pane, place the following code:

  ```
  Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal target As Range)
      If target.Column = 1 Then ChangeColor target '<--| if any changed cell is in column A then call the color handler sub
  End Sub
  ```
- in the same code pane or in any other Module, place the following code

  ```
  Sub ChangeColor(target As Range)
      Dim colorIndex1 As Long, colorIndex2 As Long

      Select Case target.Value
          Case 1
              colorIndex1 = 4 'green
              colorIndex2 = 3 'red
          Case 2
              colorIndex1 = 3 'red
              colorIndex2 = 4 'green

          Case 3 To 5
              colorIndex1 = 5 'blue
              colorIndex2 = 6 'yellow

          Case Else
              colorIndex1 = xlColorIndexNone
              colorIndex2 = xlColorIndexNone
      End Select

      target.Range("B1,C1,E1,H1").Interior.ColorIndex = colorIndex1
      target.Range("D1,F1,G1,J1").Interior.ColorIndex = colorIndex2
  End Sub
  ```

as you see, you can play around with every `Case` just changing `colorIndex1` and `colorIndex2` as per your need

furthermore a single `Case` can handle a range of target values like `Case 3 To 5` and the likes, and let you reduce significantly the typing burden