# Change cells color by value - value typin: by hand and paste / clone

Tags: vba, excel, cell

I solve my problem on this thema: [If value will change, change few cells color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41671404/if-value-will-change-change-few-cells-color)

But now I have new issue. If I type numbers "by hand" in Column A, everything is ok. But if I want paste / clone value to more cells I have error `Laufzeitfehler 13 ; Typen unverträglich`

```
    Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim LastRow As Long

LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1:A" & LastRow)) Is Nothing Then
    Select Case Target.Value
        Case "1" '<-- put the rest of your cases here
            Range("B" & Target.Row & ":H" & Target.Row).Interior.ColorIndex = 4  'green
            Range("I" & Target.Row & ":M" & Target.Row).Interior.ColorIndex = 15  'grau
        Case "2", "3" '<-- put the rest of your cases here
            Range("B" & Target.Row & ":D" & Target.Row & ",E" & Target.Row & ":G" & Target.Row).Interior.ColorIndex = 4  'green
            Range("H" & Target.Row & ":M" & Target.Row).Interior.ColorIndex = 15  'grau
        Case Else
            Range("B" & Target.Row & ":M" & Target.Row).Interior.ColorIndex = 0
    End Select
End If

End Sub
```

How to solve this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you have 
    `Select Case Target.Value` and you give a multicell range.
Probably you try something like
    `Select Case Target.Cells(1).Value` in stead of `Select Case Target.Value` and see whether the answer is what you expect.

Edit:
The change `Target.Row` to `Target.Rows` in your script.

Comment: With this changes i have no error. But script not work for all rows.

Comment: Work only for one next row (color will change only i next one row).